# Running Time of The Below Code of Prim's Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

The Naive Implementation of prim's Algo should give a running time of O(mn) .But I have 3 for loops in the Prim Function (making the running time cubic). Where am I going wrong ?

```
void Graph::Prim (const int src)                 //Nodes start from 1 to n-1
{                                                // n = Nodes+1.

   NodeExplored[src] = true;

  for(int i=1; i<n-1;++i)                         //n-2 iterations
   {
      int minIndex;
      int minEW = 10000;
      int svIndex;

     for( int sv =1;sv < n;sv++)                 //To check for Explored nodes
       {
         if(NodeExplored[sv]==true)
            {
              for(auto i = G[sv].begin();i!= G[sv].end();++i)
              {                                 //To scan through the edges from sv.

                  int dv = i->first;           //Destination Vertex
                  int ew = i->second;          //Edge Weight b/w sv & dv.

                  if(NodeExplored[dv]==false && ew < minEW)
                  {
                      minEW = ew;
                      minIndex = dv;
                      svIndex = sv;
                  }
              }
          }
      }

  NodeExplored[minIndex] = true;

  MST[svIndex].push_back(make_pair(minIndex,minEW));
  MST[minIndex].push_back(make_pair(svIndex,minEW));

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most inner loop will account for most of the nodes discovery. So, the outer loops will fail on the condition `if(NodeExplored[sv]==true)` and not doing anything, thus the O(M^2) time solution.

Better approaches can be considered, like a queue for not going through all the nodes (thus the outer loops would transform into a while loop).

A clearly described solution is presented here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-5-prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-2/

Comment: Instead of a queue, would a vector (that will store the "Explored Nodes") work ? So instead of scanning through all vertices [for( int sv =1; sv < n; sv++)] .I can  traverse through the vector which precisely contains only the Explored Nodes.